# Copying files to EC2 using SCP: Permission denied

Tags: amazon-web-services

Here's my copy cmd: `sudo scp -i keypair.pem bot.py db.py ubuntu@ec2-[ip].us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:viennabot`

When I run this I get the following error and I'm not sure why:

```
scp: viennabot/db.py: Permission denied
```

Comment: Run with `-v` to debug

Comment: Did you try copying only one file? Also, try like this `scp -i keypair.pem bot.py ubuntu@[ip_address]:~`

Comment: Yes I started with one and it did the same thing just permission denied for that file.